# SoapClient Access Denied

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Wanted to connect some external API to WooCommerce. In attached documentation i got sample code that returns me this error message :

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [1] Access Denied

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'q_woo_order');
function q_woo_order($order_id)
{
    $c = new SoapClient('https://somewebsite.com/api/soap/?wsdl', array('trace' => true, 'exceptions' => true, 'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT));
    $session = $c->login('user', 'password');
    var_dump($session);
    die;
}
```

If I try some random username and password, got this error

> The username or password you provided is incorrect

So I am assuming login data are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Is the URL https://somewebsite.com/api/soap/?wsdl reachable ?

I had the issue with an extennal client calling my webservice : he was not able to reach the "?wsdl" URL but it's working with the direct URL of the wsdl file that is like https://somewebsite.com/api/soap/wsdl/wsdlfile.wsdl

Comment: It is. For this login() method, it has:
<portType name="WF_Api_Soap_HandlerPortType">
<operation name="login">
<documentation>Login user and retrive session id</documentation>
<input message="typens:loginRequest"/>
<output message="typens:loginResponse"/>
</operation>

I dont know is this format correct